# How do I format the "money" data type in a CSV file for a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, csv

For a project I'm creating sample data in .csv files but one of the datatypes is "Money" but I haven't used this data type before.  How would I format the numbers in the .csv file for the sample data?  Would it be something like "3000.00" similar to a float?

Comment: are try to export the `csv` data into mysql?

Comment: I am trying to create the csv files.  After I create the CSV files a team-mate will be creating the scripts to import it into our database to test our program.  My goal is to create .CSV files that will import into the database without problems by correctly formatting the sample data.

Comment: I do not believe that MySQL has specific "money" type.  Where do you see it?

Comment: mysql has float type to set the decimal value. I think in CSV you simply put the data this way: `12345.99`

Comment: It's on the database diagram that I was given.  MySQL doesn't have a Money datatype?

Comment: Hm, that's interesting I think you may be right.  I think Microsoft's SQL Server has a Money datatype but I don't think MySQL has it.

Comment: just make it float(9,2) etc